# VB.NET connection to MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, connection

I get an error when I am trying to connect to a Microsoft Access DB using VB.NET. I see examples all over the web. My code looks like those examples, however I am getting a build error message stating:

> Type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' is not defined.

I have tried adding some kind of import statement for the `system.data.oledb`... but that does not seem to work. My code is below. It is a basic connection so I am thinking that I am missing some kind of add in, library, or setting. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function TestMain(ByVal args() As Object) As Object
    ' Connection String to MS Access DB
    Dim connectStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                             "Data Source=C:\Users\DMalerman\keyword.accdb;" & _
                             "Persist Security Info=False;"
    MsgBox(connectStr)
    ' Create connection to the db
    Using connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectStr)
        ' Create the SQL Query
        Dim readQuery As String = "Select KeywordDriver.ScriptName from KeywordDriver " & _
                                    "where KeywordDriver.Keyword = test"
        Dim queryCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(readQuery, connection)

        'Open the Connection
        connection.Open()

        ' Query the Database
        Dim dbReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader()

        ' Loop until there is nothing left to read
        While dbReader.Read()
            Dim sKeyword As String = ""
            sKeyword = dbReader.GetString(0)
            MsgBox(sKeyword)
        End While
        ' Close the Reader
        dbReader.Close()

    End Using

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
imports System.Data.OleDb
```

?
if so, did it give you an error?

Comment: I have done that before.  When I add that I get an additional error.  - Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Data.OleDb' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.
- Type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' is not defined.

Comment: you may need to reinstall Visual Studio, or at least the component that contains that code.  It's not your code that's the problem, it's the fact that you can't use your code because you're missing basic files.

Comment: I was thinking that may be it.  This sounds to be a basic library that is simply not found.  Is there a way to find out what module this may be in, example like a service pack or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to modify this line:
 `Dim queryCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(readQuery, connection)`

by putting these only:
 `Dim queryCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(readQuery)`
`queryCommand.Connection = connection`

Comment: I get the same error.   Type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' is not defined.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It really feels like I don't have the system.data.dll or something along those lines. This code seems pretty basic to me and should work fine given that the software has what it needs.

Comment: I was just reading some search results where I came across this "make sure you added the reference of assembly system.data and using right framework settings and assembly".  sounds promising.  can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: No no the problem is that Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on your local machine. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 try to download it from here and test your code. I'm waiting, but take ur time and test your code step by step using F10

Comment: Still the same.  I installed the file and rebooted.  Is there anything else I was supposed to do?

Comment: Honestly, im facing the same problem as yours, i think both of us are running 64 bits computer! Once i find out the solution i'll post back. I'll do my best!

Comment: I'd suggest you use JET instead of ACE, as you're running a 64 bits computer. I think it's worth to try :)

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
    Public str As String
    Public con As OleDbConnection
    Public cmd As OleDbCommand
    Public dtreader As OleDbDataReader
    Public dtadapter As OleDbDataAdapter

```
Public Sub openconn()
    str = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdb"
    con = New OleDbConnection(str)

    Try
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("gagal koneksi")
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Module